# Plot data over time using 2 variables of start date and end date

Tags: r

I have a dataset that has around 2000 rows.
Each row is a hospital encounter for ICU Admissions. This is data collected over 5 years

The variables of interest are: Encounter Number, Diagnosis Category, Admit Date, Discharge Date

What I want to do is try and plot the ICU occupancy for each day over these 5 years.
Example:

Encounter Number : 786786
Diagnosis Category : Tuberculosis
Admit Date : 2022-01-20
Discharge Date : 2022-01-30

Therefore this patient stayed in the ICU for 10 days starting from 01.20 to 01.30.

There will be other encounters for another diagnosis -
Encounter Number : 786786
Diagnosis Category : Cancer
Admit Date : 2022-01-21
Discharge Date : 2022-01-28

End goal is to plot the ICU occupancy for EACH date starting from the EARLIEST Admit Date and the LATEST Discharge Date (x - axis) by Diagnosis Category.
For each date on the x-axis for the 5 year time period, there will be a bar for the diagnosis category.

How can I go about doing this?

Thanks (:

Comment: You will get faster, better help if you share your data in a reproducible form.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem myself many times before. The algorithm to count the occupancy is essentially just creating a vector of the days you want to plot, then for each day, counting how many people were admitted before that day and discharged after that day.

We need some realistic data. Given that you have 2000 admissions over the 5 years, and given mean ICU length of stay is typically 3.5 days with a gamma or lognormal type distribution, we can create some reasonable simulated data like this:

```r
# Make data reproducible
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(Admit_date = sample(seq(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01"),
                                         as.POSIXct("2020-01-01"), "day"),
                                     2000, TRUE),
                 Diagnosis_category = sample(c("Respiratory",
                                               "Infective",
                                               "Post-op",
                                               "Trauma"), 2000, TRUE),
                 Encounter_number = 56789123 + 1:2000)

df$Discharge_date <- df$Admit_date + 86400 * rgamma(2000, sh = 2, scale = 1.75)
df$Discharge_date <- as.Date(df$Discharge_date)
df$Admit_date <- as.Date(df$Admit_date)
df <- df[order(df$Admit_date), c(3, 1, 4, 2)]
rownames(df) <- NULL

head(df)
#>   Encounter_number Admit_date Discharge_date Diagnosis_category
#> 1         56790418 2015-01-01     2015-01-02            Post-op
#> 2         56789614 2015-01-05     2015-01-10            Post-op
#> 3         56790100 2015-01-05     2015-01-12            Post-op
#> 4         56790644 2015-01-07     2015-01-07             Trauma
#> 5         56789943 2015-01-08     2015-01-09        Respiratory
#> 6         56790066 2015-01-08     2015-01-13             Trauma
```

Assuming this is similar to your own data, we can now count the occupancy for each day like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create vector of all dates you wish to plot
days <- seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-01"), "day")

plot_df <- df %>%
  group_by(Diagnosis_category) %>%
  summarize(date = days, count = sapply(days, function(x) {
              sum(Admit_date <= x & Discharge_date >= x)
  }))
```

Now we are ready to plot. In my example, we only have 4 diagnostic categories, and trying to plot over 1600 columns on a single panel is already challenging. If you try to put all your diagnostic categories over 5 years in a single panel, you will get a total mess. This is made worse by the fact that you will only ever have a handful of patients in each diagnostic category (other than during Covid peaks), so the plot will only have a few discrete steps in it. I think it would be best to use facets in this case:

```r
ggplot(plot_df, aes(date, count, fill = Diagnosis_category,
                    color = Diagnosis_category)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(.~Diagnosis_category) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Unless there is a specific point you wish your data to make with this kind of plot (like massive occupancy spikes during Covid surges), you might want to think of a different summary measure. You could try grouping `plot_df` by diagnostic category and month, then calculating average monthly occupancy.